# regex to ensure a string contains not more than a single number

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string contains only a single number, and if it contains more than a single number throw an exception:

(D*?\d+\D+\d+D*)

```
private static void assertOnlyOneNumber(String input) {
        if (input.matches(("(D*?\\d+\\D+\\d+D*)"))) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Assertion failed! String contains more than a single number: "
                    + input);
        }
    }
```

So, e.g. the following should match and throw an exception:

- 42'12
- 1h22min
- 01:23:22
- ca.120min, 200min, 300min

And the following should NOT match and thus be regarded as valid:

- 12 Minutes
- 141'
- ca.22min

It seems my regex works out ok, but it's quite easy to get it wrong, thus my question.

Background: Basically I do a conversion from a string-field to an integer-field, where I interpret the string field as duration in minutes. Therefor, I first run this check to make sure there is not more than one number in the string, and after that I strip off a fixed array of known tokens (like 'Minutes', 'min', etc.) and finally try via Integer.parseInt() if I can convert it.

If yes, I got my duration in minutes, otherwise I throw an exception.

Comment: Huh? Every single input you mentioned contains more than one number.

Comment: @Michael I guess he means a single multi-digit number (in the mathematical sense), not a single number character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep if in one line, you can still simplifiy you regex to `.*\\d\\D+\\d.*`.

It might be easier to do multiple checks, though, especially if you want to change it to "no more than x numbers":

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);
for (int i = 0; i < allowedNumber; i++)
    m.find();
if (m.find())
    throw new RuntimeException(...);
```

A merge between both ways is contructing the regex based on the number of allowed occurrences:

```
String regex = Stream.generate(() -> "\\d+").limit(allowedNumber + 1).collect(joining("\\D+", ".*", ".*"))

// non-stream equivalent
String regex = ".*\\d+";
for (int i = 0; i < allowedNumber; i++) {
    regex += "\\D+\\d+";
}
regex += ".*";

if (input.matches(regex)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(...);
}
```

Comment: + I like it because it is easy to read and reduced complexity of the code IMHO --- i'd but braces though *hehe* ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan me too, to be honest. But your IDE will take care of that ;)

Comment: +1 for the shorter regex! What I don't quite like is the nested if-structure, though.

As for the Stream-API way for building the regex, allowedNumber would be zero for my current case, right? Looks fancy, but I don't know if I'd understand what it does a week later :) but I guess that's just me and the Stream-API.

Comment: @SebastianRiemer You can flatten the stacked if with a for-loop in which you call `find()` `allowedNumber` times. After that, you call it once more, and if it still return true, you throw an exception. For the stream, `allowedNumber` would be 1, and when the input matches the regex, you throw an exception. This stream can also be replaced with loop easiliy. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @SebastianRiemer I've also replaced the stacked `if` with a `for-loop`. You could of course break the loop earlier as soon as `find` returns `false` (especially if you wanted larger `allowedNumbers`).

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
private static void assertOnlyOneNumber(String input) {
        if (input.matches(".*\\d+\\D+\\d.*")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Assertion failed! String contains more than a single number: "
                    + input);
        }
    }
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqnwnT/1)

Regex `.*\\d+\\D+\\d.*` will match an input with at least 2 sets of numbers.

Comment: Would .*\\d\\D+\\d.* also work? I guess it does not really matter, whether the .* matches the rest of the other digits

Comment: Since we are using this in `matches` method, we will need to match complete input to get `true` value returned. If you use `Pattern, Mtacher` and then `matcher.find()` then using `\\d\\D+\\d` will be fine.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't read your comment properly, yes `.*\\d\\D+\\d.*` will work fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

private static void assertOnlyOneNumber(String input) {
    Matcher m = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    int count = 0;
    while(m.find()) count++;
    // != 1 ensure that the input contains exactly one number (not more, not less)
    // if "not more than one" is the intended behaviour just use > 1
    if(count != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Assertion failed! String contains more than a single number: "
                + input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?:\d+(?:[^\d\n]|$)+?){2,}
```

Explanation:

```
                        // Matches group composed of
(?:\d+                  // number and
      (?:[^\d\n]|       // not number OR
                 $)+?    //    end of line
 ) {2,}                 // at least two times
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EGFTeX/4/)